# Aligning tableView in specific place of ViewController in Swift

Tags: xcode, uitableview, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to place a tableView in a specific position in ViewController (from half of the page to bottom). But anytime when I am trying to use Constrains the tableView is getting lost somewhere (even if I add Horizontal and Vertical centre in container)

here is the image of my storyboard in assistant editor and view controller scene
[image: Main.storyboard View]

and here is a image after adding constrains
[image: IMG]

Comment: What constraints did you add? It doesn't look like you have enough constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I just fixed in the simplest way by just adding missing constrains.